# Zabbix 2.2 API get Trigger history

Tags: zabbix

I am looking for a way to fetch the history of a certain trigger. I read the API and I don't find the correct API get.

I'm looking for something similar than what zabbix does in their frontend.

[image: Trigger history]

Hope you can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution,but it requires 2 API calls.

First get events (event.get), with source = 0. Source 0 means events generated by a trigger.

Extract all "objectids", as they point to the trigger.
Then, do trigger.get with triggerids = list of extracted objectids

Then do some manual mapping until you have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In Zabbix, "trigger history" consists of events, thus you would use the [event.get](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api/reference/event/get) API method.

Comment: If I use that, and get all events with source = trigger I receive an array with data like:

    {
      "groupid": "278",
      "eventid": "133846041",
      "source": "0",
      "object": "0",
      "objectid": "76343",
      "clock": "1480253837",
      "value": "0",
      "acknowledged": "0",
      "ns": "710382954"
    }  
How can I know which trigger the event came from?

Comment: The event object page at https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api/reference/event/object says that for trigger events the object is the trigger, and `objectid` is "ID of the related object." - thus it should be the trigger ID.